# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to deploy a model using python flask. but there is an error "Dataframe has no project attribute". anyone can help me?

**the following is the source code of the model:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from sklearn import preprocessing

dataset = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Evy Setia Oktaviani/Documents/New folder/Data Training/Data new bgt/Data coba new bgt lagi.csv')

dataset = dataset.drop(columns=['NIM', 'NAMA', 'IP Semester 1', 'IP Semester 2', 'IP Semester 3', 'IP Semester 4', 'IP Semester 5','IPK','Predikat IPK'])

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
enc = LabelEncoder()

dataset['JALUR'] = enc.fit_transform(dataset['JALUR'].values)
dataset['Predikat IP Semester 1'] = enc.fit_transform(dataset['Predikat IP Semester 1'].values)
dataset['Predikat IP Semester 2'] = enc.fit_transform(dataset['Predikat IP Semester 2'].values)
dataset['Predikat IP Semester 3'] = enc.fit_transform(dataset['Predikat IP Semester 3'].values)
dataset['Predikat  IP Semester 4'] = enc.fit_transform(dataset['Predikat  IP Semester 4'].values)
dataset['Predikat IP Semester 5'] = enc.fit_transform(dataset['Predikat IP Semester 5'].values)
dataset['JK'] = enc.fit_transform(dataset['JK'].values)
dataset['Asal Sekolah'] = enc.fit_transform(dataset['Asal Sekolah'].values)
dataset['Kelulusan'] = enc.fit_transform(dataset['Kelulusan'].values)

# labelEncoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

# category_col =['JALUR', 'Predikat IP Semester 1', 'Predikat IP Semester 2', 'Predikat IP Semester 3', 'Predikat IP Semester 4',
#                'Predikat IP Semester 5', 'JK', 'Asal Sekolah', 'Kelulusan']
# mapping_dict ={}
# for col in category_col:
#     dataset[col] = labelEncoder.fit_transform(dataset[col])
 
#     le_name_mapping = dict(zip(labelEncoder.classes_,
#                         labelEncoder.transform(labelEncoder.classes_)))
 
#     mapping_dict[col]= le_name_mapping
#     print(mapping_dict)

x = dataset.drop(['Kelulusan'], axis=1)
y = dataset['Kelulusan']


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

x_train, x_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

oversample = SMOTE()
x_train, y_train = oversample.fit_resample(x_train, y_train)

from sklearn import tree 
model = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, 
                                    max_depth = None, min_samples_split=2, 
                                    min_samples_leaf=1,min_weight_fraction_leaf=0,
                                    max_leaf_nodes=None,min_impurity_decrease=0)

clf = model.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_pred= clf.predict(x_test)

cm = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
print ("Confusion Matrix")
print (cm)
akurasi = classification_report(y_test, y_pred)
print ("Tingkat akurasi algoritma c45")
print ("akurasi : ", akurasi)
akurasi = accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)
print ("Tingkat akurasi : %d "%(akurasi*100))

from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
export_graphviz(model, out_file="Tree_kelulusuan.dot", class_names=["TERLAMBAT","TEPAT"],
                 impurity=False, filled=True)

# import graphviz

# with open ("Tree_kelulusuan.dot") as fig:
#   dot_graph = fig.read()
#   graph=graphviz.Source(dot_graph)

# graph.view()

pickle.dump(dataset, open("model.pkl", "wb"))

# from joblib import dump

# dump(model, 'model.joblib')
```

**the following is the source code of the form**

```
    {% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block body %}

<main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
    <div
        class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">Prediksi</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="Loader">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="spinner-border text-primary" style="width: 5rem; height: 5rem;" role="status">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Prediksi</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{{url_for('tambahuser')}}" method="POST">
              <div class="mb -3">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nama:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nama" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">NIM:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nim" id="recipient-name">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="validationCustom04" class="form-label">Jenis Kelamin</label>
                <select class="form-select" id="validationCustom04" name="level" required>
                  <option selected disabled value="">Pilih...</option>
                  <option value="Laki-Laki">Laki-Laki</option>
                  <option value="Perempuan">Perempuan</option>
                </select>
          </div>
              <div class="mb -3">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Kelas:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nama" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
              </div>
              <div class="mb -3">
                <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Angkatan:</label>
                <input type="text" name="nama" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Input</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <br><br>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          Data Mahasiswa
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
            <thead class="table table-dark">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">No.</th>
                <th scope="col">Nama</th>
                <th scope="col">NIM</th>
                <th scope="col">Jenis Kelamin</th>
                <th scope="col">Kelas</th>
                <th scope="col">Angkatan</th>
                <th scope="col">Aksi</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- <tbody>
              {% for dt in data%}
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">{{loop.index}}</th>
                <td>{{dt.username}}</td>
                <td>{{dt.level}}</td>
                <td>
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Edit</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody> -->
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
</div> 
    
    {% endblock %}
```

**and here is the source code for run app.py**

```
    from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/dashboard')
# @login_dulu
def dashboard():
     return render_template('dashboard.html')
def ValuePredictor(to_predict_list):
    to_predict = np.array(to_predict_list).reshape(1,7)
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open("model2.pkl", "rb"))
    result = loaded_model.predict(to_predict)
    return result[0]
 
@app.route('/result', methods = ['POST'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        to_predict_list = request.form.to_dict()
        to_predict_list = list(to_predict_list.values())
        to_predict_list = list(map(int, to_predict_list))
        result = ValuePredictor(to_predict_list)       
        if int(result)==1:
            prediction ='Terlambat'
        else:
            prediction ='Tepat Waktu'           
        return render_template("prediksi.html", prediction = prediction)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

if anyone understand please help me thank you

Comment: `predict` is model function, not features. the call `clf.predict()` is wrong, it must be `model.predict()`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).